# How to record a stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, websocket, stream, record

I have a video stream that I get through a websocket in my app and I want to know if i can record it like it is a video without showing it on the screen ?
I'd love to know how to do it if anyone know, thanks!

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way to record my stream with FFMPEG and a tutorial in this video :
https://youtu.be/Z5vBs8Mk5rA?t=581

It work fine for now